# Efficient way to find intersection of two vectors with respect to two members of vector objects

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, intersection

I have two vectors holding data objects. Each data object is holding coordinates and some other data. The vectors will always be sorted (first for the x coordinates and then for the y coordinates). I'm trying to delete all objects from both vectors that have coordinates that can not be found in both of the vectors. Here's an MWE of what I'm currently doing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>


struct foo{
  foo()=default;
  foo(int x, int y, double data):x(x),y(y),data(data){}
  int x;
  int y;
  double data;
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<foo> vec1=std::vector<foo>(7);
  std::vector<foo> vec2=std::vector<foo>(4);

  vec1={foo(1,1,0.),foo(1,2,0.),foo(2,1,0.),foo(2,2,0.),foo(2,3,0.),foo(3,1,0.),foo(3,2,0.)};
  vec2={foo(1,2,0.),foo(1,3,0.),foo(2,1,0.),foo(3,1,0.)};

  for(auto it1=vec1.begin(); it1!=vec1.end();){
    auto cur_element=*it1;
    auto intersec = std::find_if(vec2.begin(),vec2.end(),[cur_element]
                                       (foo & comp_element)->bool{
        return((cur_element.x==comp_element.x) && (cur_element.y==comp_element.y));
  });
    if(intersec==vec2.end()) it1=vec1.erase(it1);
    else ++it1;

  }

  for(auto it2=vec2.begin(); it2!=vec2.end();){
    auto cur_element=*it2;
    auto intersec = std::find_if(vec1.begin(),vec1.end(),[cur_element]
                                       (foo & comp_element)->bool{
        return((cur_element.x==comp_element.x) && (cur_element.y==comp_element.y));
  });
    if(intersec==vec1.end()) it2=vec2.erase(it2);
    else ++it2;
  }

  std::cout<<"vec1:\n";
  for(auto i: vec1) std::cout<<i.x<<" "<<i.y<<"\n";
  std::cout<<"\nvec2:\n";
  for(auto i: vec2) std::cout<<i.x<<" "<<i.y<<"\n";

  return 0;
}
```

It works and gives me the expected output.
Anyway it seems really unefficient having to loop through both of the vectors. Is there a more efficient way to achieve the same output?

EDIT: It's not enough to obtain the coordinates that are represented in both vectors. What I need is an efficient way to delete the "wrong" objects from both vectors.

Comment: You can do it linearly similar to [std::set_symmetric_difference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_symmetric_difference)

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks. Give me a moment, I'll read into that.

Comment: @Jarod42 Not sure if I got it right, but I think this won't help me. I really need to end up with the two original vectors just without those elements, whose coordinates cannot be found in both of them. So using std::set_symmetric_difference will only give me the coordinates that cannot be found in both vectors, right? after that I would still need to loop through both vectors to delete all elements that have the same coordinates as the output of std::set_symmetric_difference. Am I wrong?

Comment: surely your outputs just 2 copies of the symmetric difference?

Comment: @RichardHodges No, it's not. The objects of the vectors hold other data, too. I thought I made that clear, by giving the `foo` struct a third member `data`. The other members of the `foo`-objects will be different for the same coordinates in the two vectors. So as said in the question, I need the original vectors. Just without those objects that have coordinates that are not represented in both vectors.

Comment: understood. thanks for clarifying.

Comment: So you want to go through both vectors at the same time (say with two iterators). Deleting while using an iterator ... you should be carefull. so maybe creating two new vectors? If the order of the two iterator is equal, then copy them to their new vectors, otherwise increase the lower one.

Comment: erase-remove idiom? otherwise see if you can use set, set_difference or set_symmetric_difference as pointed out by another comment.

Comment: I meant, you can use the same structural code, only action to take is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your two vectors are sorted already – perfect!

First, assuming a comparison function (with up-coming C++20, this would get the space-ship operator...):

```
int compare(foo const& l, foo const& r)
{
   return l.x != r.x ? l.x - r.x : l.y - r.y;
}
```

Now you can use it in the algorithm:

```
auto i1 = v1.begin();
auto i2 = v2.begin();

auto end1 = i1;
auto end2 = i2;

while(i1 != v1.end() && i2 != v2.end())
{
    int cmp = compare(*i1, *i2);
    if(cmp < 0)
    {
        // skip element
        ++i1;
    }
    else if(cmp > 0)
    {
        ++i2;
    }
    else
    {
        // matching element found, keep in both vectors...
        if(i1 != end1)
            *end1 = std::move(*i1);
        ++i1;
        ++end1;
        if(i2 != end2)
            *end2 = std::move(*i2);
        ++i2;
        ++end2;

        // if you can rely on move (or fallback copy) assignment
        // checking for self assignment, the following simpler
        // alternative can be used instead:

        //*end1++ = std::move(*i1++);
        //*end2++ = std::move(*i2++);
    }
}
v1.erase(end1, v1.end());
v2.erase(end2, v2.end());
```

Linear in both vectors...

The algorithm just moves the elements to be kept to front and finally drops all the overdue ones – similarly as would `std::remove_if` do...

Comment: This works fine, upvote for that. I'll accept one of the other two answers though, since they implemented the whole thing including the comparisson.

Answer (score 1):

I think this solution is linear and does what you want.

Possible further enhancement:

- for large vectors with large areas of non-intersection, it may be worth caching regions to erase.
- another strategy if `data` is cheap to move, is to conditionally build output vectors from input vectors and swap

```
struct foo_less
{
    bool operator()(foo const&l, foo const& r) const
    {
        return std::tie(l.x, l.y) < std::tie(r.x, r.y);
    }
};

void remove_non_matching(std::vector<foo>& l, std::vector<foo>& r)
{
    constexpr auto less = foo_less();
    assert(std::is_sorted(l.begin(), l.end(), less));
    assert(std::is_sorted(r.begin(), r.end(), less));

    auto lcurrent = l.begin(), rcurrent = r.begin();

    while (lcurrent != l.end() && rcurrent != r.end())
    {
        if (less(*lcurrent, *rcurrent))
            lcurrent = l.erase(lcurrent);
        else if(less(*rcurrent, *lcurrent))
            rcurrent = r.erase(rcurrent);
        else
        {
            ++lcurrent;
            ++rcurrent;
        }
    }

    l.erase(lcurrent, l.end());
    r.erase(rcurrent, r.end());
}
```

alternative approach will cost more memory but is theoretically more efficient:

```
void remove_non_matching_alt(std::vector<foo>& l, std::vector<foo>& r)
{
    constexpr auto less = foo_less();
    assert(std::is_sorted(l.begin(), l.end(), less));
    assert(std::is_sorted(r.begin(), r.end(), less));

    auto lresult = std::vector<foo>(), rresult = std::vector<foo>();
    auto sz = std::min(l.size(), r.size());
    lresult.reserve(sz);
    rresult.reserve(sz);


    auto lcurrent = l.begin(), rcurrent = r.begin();

    while (lcurrent != l.end() && rcurrent != r.end())
    {
        if (less(*lcurrent, *rcurrent))
            ++lcurrent;
        else if(less(*rcurrent, *lcurrent))
            ++rcurrent;
        else
        {
            lresult.push_back(std::move(*lcurrent++));
            rresult.push_back(std::move(*rcurrent++));
        }
    }

    l.swap(lresult);
    r.swap(rresult);
}
```

Similar but uses a thread_local persistent cache to avoid un-necessary memory allocations:

```
void remove_non_matching_alt_faster(std::vector<foo>& l, std::vector<foo>& r)
{
    constexpr auto less = foo_less();
    assert(std::is_sorted(l.begin(), l.end(), less));
    assert(std::is_sorted(r.begin(), r.end(), less));

    // optimisation - minimise memory allocations on subsequent calls while maintaining
    // thread-safety
    static thread_local auto lresult = std::vector<foo>(), rresult = std::vector<foo>();

    auto sz = std::min(l.size(), r.size());
    lresult.reserve(sz);
    rresult.reserve(sz);


    auto lcurrent = l.begin(), rcurrent = r.begin();

    while (lcurrent != l.end() && rcurrent != r.end())
    {
        if (less(*lcurrent, *rcurrent))
            ++lcurrent;
        else if(less(*rcurrent, *lcurrent))
            ++rcurrent;
        else
        {
            lresult.push_back(std::move(*lcurrent++));
            rresult.push_back(std::move(*rcurrent++));
        }
    }

    l.swap(lresult);
    r.swap(rresult);

    // ensure destructors of discarded 'data' are called and prep for next call
    lresult.clear();
    rresult.clear();
}
```

Comment: This ressembles pretty much my original approach - solely, repeatedly `erase`-ing elements will move elements to front much more often than actually needed...

Comment: @Aconcagua updated with 3rd option. An alternative approach would involve a map of 'deleted regions' and a final delete cycle. However, I don't think it would outperform the 3rd implementation.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, upvoted. I'll look into it later and accept either this or the answer of @jdehesa.

Answer (score 1):

This is my approach, in a [erase–remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) style, iterating only once through the vectors:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>

struct foo
{
  foo() = default;
  foo(int x, int y, double data) : x(x), y(y), data(data) {}
  int x;
  int y;
  double data;
};

// Maybe better as overloaded operators
int compare_foo(const foo& foo1, const foo& foo2)
{
  if (foo1.x < foo2.x) return -1;
  if (foo1.x > foo2.x) return +1;
  if (foo1.y < foo2.y) return -1;
  if (foo1.y > foo2.y) return +1;
  return 0;
}

std::tuple<std::vector<foo>::iterator, std::vector<foo>::iterator>
remove_difference(std::vector<foo>& vec1, std::vector<foo>& vec2)
{
  typedef std::vector<foo>::iterator iterator;
  iterator it1 = vec1.begin();
  size_t shift1 = 0;
  iterator it2 = vec2.begin();
  size_t shift2 = 0;
  while (it1 != vec1.end() && it2 != vec2.end())
  {
    int cmp = compare_foo(*it1, *it2);
    if (cmp < 0)
    {
      ++it1;
      shift1++;
    }
    else if (cmp > 0)
    {
      ++it2;
      shift2++;
    }
    else
    {
      std::iter_swap(it1, std::prev(it1, shift1));
      ++it1;
      std::iter_swap(it2, std::prev(it2, shift2));
      ++it2;
    }
  }
  return std::make_tuple(std::prev(it1, shift1), std::prev(it2, shift2));
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<foo> vec1=std::vector<foo>(7);
  std::vector<foo> vec2=std::vector<foo>(4);

  vec1={foo(1,1,0.),foo(1,2,0.),foo(2,1,0.),foo(2,2,0.),foo(2,3,0.),foo(3,1,0.),foo(3,2,0.)};
  vec2={foo(1,2,0.),foo(1,3,0.),foo(2,1,0.),foo(3,1,0.)};

  auto remove_iters = remove_difference(vec1, vec2);
  vec1.erase(std::get<0>(remove_iters), vec1.end());
  vec2.erase(std::get<1>(remove_iters), vec2.end());

  std::cout<<"vec1:\n";
  for(auto i: vec1) std::cout<<i.x<<" "<<i.y<<"\n";
  std::cout<<"\nvec2:\n";
  for(auto i: vec2) std::cout<<i.x<<" "<<i.y<<"\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
vec1:
1 2
2 1
3 1

vec2:
1 2
2 1
3 1
```

The only thing to not is that this assumes that there are no repeated coordinates, or more specifically, that they are repeated the same number of times on both vectors, and "extra" repetitions would be removed (you could adapt the algorithm to change that if you needed, although it would make the code a bit uglier).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this? You choose first which vector is bigger then iterate (mainly) over the bigger one and check inside the other one.

```
int main()
{
   std::vector<foo> vec1=std::vector<foo>(7);
   std::vector<foo> vec2=std::vector<foo>(4);

   vec1={foo(1,1,0.),foo(1,2,0.),foo(2,1,0.),foo(2,2,0.),foo(2,3,0.),foo(3,1,0.),foo(3,2,0.)};
   vec2={foo(1,2,0.),foo(1,3,0.),foo(2,1,0.),foo(3,1,0.)};

   std::vector<foo>::iterator it_begin;
   std::vector<foo>::iterator it_end;
   std::vector<foo>* main;
   std::vector<foo>* other;

   if( vec1.size() > vec2.size() ) {
      it_begin = vec1.begin();
      it_end   = vec1.end(); 
      main     = &vec1;
      other    = &vec2; 
   }
   else {
       it_begin = vec2.begin();
       it_end   = vec2.end();
       main     = &vec2;
       other    = &vec1;
   }

   std::vector<foo> new_vec;
   for( it_begin; it_begin != it_end; ++it_begin ) {
      auto cur_element = *it_begin;
      auto intersec = std::find_if( other->begin(),other->end(),[cur_element]
                                   (foo & comp_element)->bool{
         return( (cur_element.x==comp_element.x ) && ( cur_element.y==comp_element.y ) );
      });

      if( intersec != other->end() )
      {
         new_vec.push_back( cur_element );
      }
   }

   vec1 = new_vec;
   vec2 = new_vec;

   std::cout<<"vec1:\n";
   for(auto i: vec1) std::cout<<i.x<<" "<<i.y<<"\n";
   std::cout<<"\nvec2:\n";
   for(auto i: vec2) std::cout<<i.x<<" "<<i.y<<"\n";

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code does not produce the same output as my code. Test my code and look at what objects are still in `vec1` and `vec2`. In yours the output is completely different and not correct.

Comment: Ah okay I am sorry miss understood the question

Comment: Do you really need both vectors? Why not just use one of them? Return a new vector and then if you need really two just copy it?

Comment: I really need both vectors. Please read my comments on the original question answering Richard Hodges questions. I'm currently adjusting and trying out the answer of @Aconcagua